# MATLAB Matrix Transformation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to transform a matrix:

```
X = [1 2; 3 4]
X = 1 2
    3 4
```

to

```
X = [1 2; 1 2; 1 2; 3 4; 3 4; 3 4]
X = 1 2
    1 2
    1 2
    3 4
    3 4
    3 4
```

and do this operation for a matrix with any number of rows.
How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice and easy way to do this using kron

```
kron(X,[1 1 1]')
```

this produces

```
     1     2
     1     2
     1     2
     3     4
     3     4
     3     4
```